# Android app does not launch in Appium

Tags: testng, appium

```
[TestNG] Running:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1898663871\testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote 
session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{appPackage=com.company.remoteOn, appActivity=com.se.appname.views.login.MainLoginActivity, browserName=Android, platformName=Android, deviceName=3a2e249, version=5.1.1}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '8c03df6', time: '2017-03-02 09:30:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'WTIN05200024L', ip: '10.179.201.254', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:114)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:132)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:92)
at com.schneider.android.app.SimpleAndroidCalcTest.setUp(SimpleAndroidCalcTest.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:656)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
```

We are trying to automate an android app using appium 1.6.4 on windows 10 machine. Android version used is 6.0.1 .

Everytime we run the script, get this error. Any idea how we could solve this issue?

Comment: Please use the appropriate formatting to identify code.

Comment: Pl update your browser configuration code

Comment: @ChandraShekhar public void f(){
   WebDriver driver;
   DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
   cap.setCapability("deviceName","95cffad2");
   cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
   cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");
   cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
   cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.xxxxxxx.remoteOn.NonProd");
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.se.xxxxxx.views.MainActivity");
 driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);  
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public void f()
{ 
      WebDriver driver;
      DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities(); 
      cap.setCapability("deviceName","95cffad2"); 
      cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android"); 
      cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1"); 
      cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android"); 
      cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.xxxxxxx.remoteOn.NonProd"); 
      cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.se.xxxxxx.views.MainActivity"); 
      driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);   
}
```

In any Automation code, Protocol definition is mandatory as URL needs HTTP here..

Comment: `Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{appPackage=com.schneiderelectric.remoteOn, appActivity=com.se.XXXx.views.MainActivity, platformVersion=6.0.1, platformName=Android, deviceName=95cffad2}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]

In appium i get this error: "Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Permission to start activity denied"

Comment: I have changed the above code too `cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"95cffad2");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,"6.0.1");
cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,"com.xxxxx.remoteOn.NonProd");
cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,"com.se.xxxxxx.views.MainActivity");
driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);`

Comment: Possible problems,
1> Check JAVA path configuration
2> Try to open android application using ADB and check further steps

Answer (score 0):

This is my last suggestion.

Add android:exported="true" in the activity of Android Manifest file and device should be in Debug Mode ( settings-> Developer Options )